# Sort GameObjects from an array to a reference point in space

Tags: sorting, unity-game-engine

I have some GameObject in an array and I'd like to sort them by distance based on a point in space. So basically I'm searching for an point sorting by distance algorithm.

I'm sure this is basic sorting algorithm stuff but I couldn't find a valid answer on Google so far.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Maybe this question fits better on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, because it requires some basic knowledge of Unity3D (at least, how to use the `Vector3` class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
System.Array.Sort<GameObject>(arrayOfGameObjects,
(g1, g2) => 
    (Vector3.Distance(target,g1.transform.position) < 
     Vector3.Distance(target,g2.transform.position))?-1:1);
```

Comment: +1: The answer is right. I suggested also a Linq alternative. I often prefer using Linq for readability and compactness of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Jerdak answer is right.
If you can use an ordered copy of the array, instead of ordering the original one, an alternative is to use `Linq` [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb534966%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) extension method to `Enumerable`:

```
Vector3 targetPos;
IEnumerable<Pet> ordered = arrayOfGameObjects.OrderBy(
    obj => Vector3.Distance(obj.transform.position,targetPos));
```